# TabWidget will not display, even though it displays in ADT editor

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-tabhost

My TabWidget will not display, even though it shows up in the Eclipse graphical editor. I can't find any reason why. Why isn't my tab bar showing?

Eclipse

[image: Imgur]

Emulator

[image: Imgur]

XML source of the activity: http://pastebin.com/Au9XFXPa

Extract from activity:

```
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>
```

Results from Android lint:

```
$ lint.bat res/layout/activity_calculator.xml
Scanning Catalyst: .
No issues found.
```

Comment: Where in your code are you including `activity_calculator.xml`?

Comment: I Recommend using Fragment instead of Tab Widget :D

Comment: @Jeff Lee. It is for Android version 8+. Fragments are not included below version 11. Most phones are still 2.3, which is API 10.

Comment: @shoerat It is included automatically as part of the activity onCreate() `setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to tell without actual code of how your activity is implemented, but seems like you need to call `setContent()` on your `TabHost`:

```
    TabHost tabs = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabs.setup();

    // Calculator
    TabHost.TabSpec calculatorTab = tabs.newTabSpec("calculator");
    calculatorTab.setContent(R.id.calculator);
    calculatorTab.setIndicator("Calculator");
    tabs.addTab(calculatorTab);

    // Home
    TabHost.TabSpec homeTab = tabs.newTabSpec("home");
    homeTab.setContent(R.id.home);
    tabs.addTab(homeTab);

    // Home
    TabHost.TabSpec faqTab = tabs.newTabSpec("faq");
    faqTab.setContent(R.id.faq);
    tabs.addTab(faqTab);
```

This should give you the idea.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused. I thought it was like the other widgets or GWT graphical editor and no programming was required.  I cleaned up the answer (tabhost, setIndicator).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Fragements` inside `TabHost`, something like this:

```
 <TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Then initialize your tabs, by doing something like this:

```
/**
 * Initialise the Tab Host
 */
private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    RedeemActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("1"),
            (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1", Activity1.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    RedeemActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("2"),
            (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2", Activity2.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    RedeemActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("3"),
            (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3", Activity3.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    // Default to first tab
    // this.onTabChanged("Tab1");
    //
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}
```